# How to set date time values?

Tags: android, datetime

In my android application, I want to set the date and time in `TextView`. In that date value I have selected and stored as a `String`. Now I want to set the `String` date value and current time.

I tried the following code. It did displayed stored date value but the time as 12.00 AM. I want **current time**?

```
String lbl_date="02-Aug-2011";
Date dateObj = new Date(lbl_date); 
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm aa",Locale.ENGLISH); 
String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);           
txt_date_start.setText(newDateStr.toString());
```

output as: `02-Aug-2011 12:00 AM`

Need: `02-Aug-2011 [current time]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Date now = new Date();

String s;

Format formatter;

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm aa",Locale.ENGLISH);

s = formatter.format(date);

txt_date_start.setText(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   TextView t=(TextView)findViewbyid(R.id.text);
    t.setText(mYear+" "+mMOnth+" "+mDay+" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this, to set current time:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
dateObj.setTime(c.getTimeInMillis());
```

Comment: current date and current time displayed.but I want only current time.date as lbl_date

Comment: Sorry I' having difficulties to understand what you are trying to do. You can have current time, e. g. in a second object, like this:   `SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String time = timeFormat.format(c.getTimeInMillis());`